# How can I get the only version form different packages in ruby

Tags: ruby

> I have to split out only the version from packages. Adding some of the
> different packages examples.

```
splunkforwarder-8.1.2-545206cc9f70-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm
netpbm-devel-10.79.00-7.el7.i686.rpm
newt-0.52.15-4.el7.i686.rpm
example-1.1.1.4.rpm
```

I need the output for above like below

```
8.1.2
10.79.00
0.52.15
1.1.1.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, such as:

```
(\d+\.)+\d+
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/Vo9KCQtfxevnUb)

For example:

```
package = "splunkforwarder-8.1.2-545206cc9f70-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm"

package[/(\d+\.)+\d+/]
  #=> "8.1.2"
```

This implementation *assumes* that the desired "version number" is the first occurrence of digits, separated by periods, in the package name. It works for all four examples you have given, as shown in the demo link.

Comment: Hey thanks Tom its working for all of them :)